# convert 132K to 132000 and 224.4M to 224,400,000 in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on pyspark dataframe which has

```html
MINFLT  MAJFLT  VSTEXT  VSIZE   RSIZE   VGROW   RGROW
132K    224.4M  11160K  0   224.4M  11160K  0K
134M    224.9K  12260K  0   224.4M  11160K  0K
132K    225.5M  11160K  0   224.4M  11160K  0K
```

and trying to get output like:

```html
  MINFLT    MAJFLT  VSTEXT  VSIZE   RSIZE   VGROW   RGROW
  132000   24400000 11160000    0   224400000   11160000 0
```

I've tried the following code:

```
df.Val = (df.RSIZE.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
      df.RSIZE.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
      .fillna(1)
      .replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```html
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-489237518a0c> in <module>
----> 1 df.Val = (df.RSIZE.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
      2           df.RSIZE.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
      3           .fillna(1)
      4           .replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check that you wanted to use regexp_replace or referring replace.
I didnt find replace in Column class. you could use regex_replace, which is present in
function module of Pyspark.

I have implement below code for you requirment:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession(sc)
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sample_src = spark.read.csv("sample_src.txt", header=True)
#  use different value for DecimalType, M and K, as per your need
converter = lambda clm, bas_vale: sf.regexp_replace(sf.col(clm),(r'[KM]'),"").cast(DecimalType(20,8)) *bas_vale

sample_src.withColumn("RSIZE", sf.when(sf.col("RSIZE").endswith("M"), converter("RSIZE", 1000000)).otherwise(converter("RSIZE",1000))).show()
```

---

**Input:**

```
+------+------+------+-----+------+------+-----+
|MINFLT|MAJFLT|VSTEXT|VSIZE| RSIZE| VGROW|RGROW|
+------+------+------+-----+------+------+-----+
|  132K|224.4M|11160K|    0|224.4M|11160K|   0K|
|  134M|224.9K|12260K|    0|224.4M|11160K|   0K|
|  132K|225.5M|11160K|    0|224.4M|11160K|   0K|
+------+------+------+-----+------+------+-----+
```

**Output:**

```
+------+------+------+-----+------------------+------+-----+
|MINFLT|MAJFLT|VSTEXT|VSIZE|             RSIZE| VGROW|RGROW|
+------+------+------+-----+------------------+------+-----+
|  132K|224.4M|11160K|    0|224400000.00000000|11160K|   0K|
|  134M|224.9K|12260K|    0|224400000.00000000|11160K|   0K|
|  132K|225.5M|11160K|    0|224400000.00000000|11160K|   0K|
+------+------+------+-----+------------------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map) and do some string manipulations and then the final calculation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import translate, coalesce, lit, substring, expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([
      ('132K', '224.4M', '11160K', '0', '224.4M', '11160K', '0K')
    , ('134M', '224.9K', '12260K', '0', '224.4M', '11160K', '0K')
    , ('132K', '225.5M', '11160K', '0', '224.4M', '11160K', '0K')
], ['MINFLT', 'MAJFLT', 'VSTEXT', 'VSIZE', 'RSIZE', 'VGROW', 'RGROW'])

# create the Map
scale_map = expr("map('K',1000, 'M',1000000, 'G', 1000000000)")

# specify column names you want to process
cols_included = {'MAJFLT', 'RSIZE'}

# define a function to do the conversion
my_convert = lambda c: (translate(c, 'KMG', '')*coalesce(scale_map[substring(c,-1,1)],lit(1))).astype('bigint').alias(c)

df_new = df.select([ my_convert(c) if c in cols_included else c for c in df.columns ])
df_new.show()
+------+---------+------+-----+---------+------+-----+
|MINFLT|   MAJFLT|VSTEXT|VSIZE|    RSIZE| VGROW|RGROW|
+------+---------+------+-----+---------+------+-----+
|  132K|224400000|11160K|    0|224400000|11160K|   0K|
|  134M|   224900|12260K|    0|224400000|11160K|   0K|
|  132K|225500000|11160K|    0|224400000|11160K|   0K|
+------+---------+------+-----+---------+------+-----+
```

**Where:** in the function `my_convert`, we use [translate(c, 'KMG', '')](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.translate) to remove chars `K`, `M` and `G` (you can do the same with regexp_replace). use [substring(c,-1,1)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring) to get the last char of the string and use it as the key to find its corresponding value from `scale_map[..]`. use [coalesce(.., lit(1))](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) to set the scale to `1` when no such key is found in `scale_map`.

Comment: In this method, if I have any other column which has string values for ('apache2','mission-contro','whoopsie')- values in new dataframe turn into null because dtypes is string

Comment: check the updated post, you need to specify columns you want to included and then use if/else in the list-comprehension.