# Convert the string from K to thousands etc., and remove space between strings in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I'd like to ask your help for transforming strings in one column in **Pyspark dataframe**.

For example,
I have a dataframe named "df" which has the following structure.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('David','5K'),('William','6M'),('Sam','1B'),('Ashely','342 1'),('Chloe','240.5 4')], ['Name','Numbers'])
```

where K = thousands, M = millions, and B = billions.

What I want to do here is (1) converting the string from K to thousands, M to millions, B to billions, and (2) removing the spaces between strings in the "Numbers" column, and then (3) changing its datatype to double. You can use regular expressions but I don't want to use pandas in this case.

This would be the desired output after transformation:

```
Names    |Numbers
---------------------------
David    |5000
William  |6000000
Sam      |1000000000
Ashely   |3421
Chloe    |240.54
```

I'd appreciate any helps from you guys!

Comment: check one of my recent posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057098/9510729, you will need to replace `G` to `B` and add SPACE into translate function: `translate(c, 'KMB ', '')` and astype to double instead of bigint

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace` and then multiply the 'Numbers' column with the appropriate 10th power:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("Numbers", when(col('Numbers').like("%K"), (regexp_replace('Numbers', 'K', '').cast('double')*1000))\
    .when(col('Numbers').like("%M"), (regexp_replace('Numbers', 'M', '').cast('double')*1000000))\
    .when(col('Numbers').like("%B"), (regexp_replace('Numbers', 'B', '').cast('double')*1000000000))\
    .otherwise((regexp_replace('Numbers', ' ', '').cast('double'))))\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+
|   Name|  Numbers|
+-------+---------+
|  David|   5000.0|
|William|6000000.0|
|    Sam|    1.0E9|
| Ashely|   3421.0|
|  Chloe|   240.54|
+-------+---------+
```

If we have `5.5K`, then the output will be `5500.0`